# Create method test keeps failing with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Alright, I keep trying to make this test work and for some reason it does not want to work. I don't know if I missed something or what but I can't figure out what the heck is going on with this code. Every thing seems to point to it being correct but I don't know. Anyway here is what I have done, which I think is correct but obviously it isn't since it keeps failing.

These are my test attributes, the invalid ones are failing for some reason.

```
let(:valid_attributes){
        @user = User.create!(:email => "email@gmail.com", :password => 'password')
            {:name => "name", :user_id => @user.id}
    } 

let(:invalid_attributes){
    @user = User.create!(:email => "email@gmail.com", :password => 'password')
        {:name => "", :user_id => @user.id} 
}
```

Here's my post request:

```
describe "POST #create" do 
        context "with valid attributes" do  
            it "describes a survey created with valid attributes" do
                expect{
                    post :create, survey: valid_attributes
                }.to change(Survey, :count).by(1)
            end

            it "redirects the user to the survey's detail page" do
                post :create, {survey: valid_attributes}
                expect(response).to redirect_to(Survey.last)
            end 
        end

        context "with invalid attributes" do 
            it "describes a survey created with invalid attributes" do 
                post :create, {survey: invalid_attributes}
                expect(assigns(:survey)).to be_a_new(Survey)
            end

            it "re-renders the new template" do 
                post :create, {survey: invalid_attributes}
                expect(response).to render_template('new')
            end 
        end 
    end
```

And of course my controller method, which is implemented, as such this shouldn't be failing, especially because it is doing exactly what that stuff indicates.

```
def create
        @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
        respond_to do |format|
            if @survey.save
                format.html { redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.' }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
            end
        end
    end
```

I'm using strong parameters as well, don't know if that makes a difference, I don't think it should but anyway this is what they have:

```
def set_survey
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def survey_params
    params.require(:survey).permit(:name, :user_id)
end
```

Finally, this is what my error messages say, which make no sense to me, especially the first one since the object seems to meet all the standards for it to be a survey.

Error 1:

```
  1) SurveysController POST #create with invalid attributes describes a survey created with invalid attributes
     Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:survey)).to be_a_new(Survey)
       expected #<Survey id: 187, name: "", user_id: 257, created_at: "2015-10-11 04:46:35", updated_at: "2015-10-11 04:46:35"> to be a new Survey(id: integer, name: string, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
     # ./spec/controllers/surveys_controller_spec.rb:82:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Error 2:

```
  2) SurveysController POST #create with invalid attributes re-renders the new template
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template('new')
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
     # ./spec/controllers/surveys_controller_spec.rb:87:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is when you send a request using `invalid_attributes`, your controller still takes the successful path through your code. You can tell from your two failures. Rendering with `<[]>` happens on a redirect, and object instances only have an `id` and `created_at` if they've been saved.

This would indicate that you're not validating presence of `name` in your `Survey` model:

```
# app/models/survey.rb
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

and thus it is saved successfully with a blank name.